# More Efficient Feature Method Than Haar-Feature For Face Detection

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision, pattern-recognition, features

The seminal work by [Viola-Jones](http://wearables.cc.gatech.edu/paper_of_week/viola01rapid.pdf)   had the most impact in face detection. It used Haar-Feature, which is fast to compute with the help of integral image method.

Is there a feature method that is more efficient (computationally) than Haar-Feature?

For example, for a $24 \times 24$ window, the computational complexity is more than $180,000$.

***Is there any feature method which has the same efficiency (or better) as obtained by Viola-Jones but less expensive computational complexity-wise?***

Comment: LBP features are integer in contrast to Haar features, so both training and detection with LBP are several times faster then with Haar features.

Comment: What do you mean by "same efficiency but less expensive"?  What distinction are you trying to draw between those two?  And given your comment, have you answered your own question?  If so, would you write an answer to your own question?

Comment: @D.W. for example, if u come up with a feature system that  takes number of operations (computational-complexity) less than $180000$ keeping the   detection rate (true-positive) same as Viola-Jones, we would consider that  "same efficiency but less expensive". The comment is just a note , its not an answer obviously , I am searching, and gathering .

Comment: Ahh, ok.  Detection rate would normally be called accuracy or detection rate or effectiveness, not efficiency; efficiency normally refers to the running time (computational complexity).  Thanks.

Comment: The method by Viola and Jones gives pretty good results for face detection in a quite short time. I doubt that you can achieve significantly better results in the same time on the same hardware with other approaches. I think recent developments focus rather on the "pretty good results" part and use much better hardware and a bit more time.

Comment: By computational complexity, do you mean that in terms of $\mathcal{O}(f(n))$-noation? What would be your $n$? The size of the image in pixel? I doubt that this is really meaningful. The Viola-Jones approach can be executed in real time. You can have an approach in the same $\mathcal{O}$-class, but much slower. Not considering additive and multiplicative constants might be ok for big instance, but makes this theoretical measure rather meaningless if you usually have instances of the same size.

Comment: For example, the problem of face detection itself becomes very different if you have 200x200 image compared to when you have a 1000x1000 image. In the small resolution image you can be relatively sure that there is only one, maybe two people. You can also make assumptions about the size of the face within the image. But for 1000x1000 this is very different. And even more for $10000 \times 10000$